# How to grep specific IP Addresses using regex?

Tags: regex, grep

My simplified sample file is as follows ... The actual file has more text and IP in it. Just to make it easier for this example.

file.txt

```
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.33
10.1.1.35
```

I would like to grep only `10.1.1.9 & 10.1.1.33`.

If I use `grep '10.1.1.[9|33]' file.txt`, this will grep everything including .35.

I know this can be achieve with `grep -v 35 file.txt`, but I wanted the solution in regex as the actual file contains more data than this sample.

What's wrong with my regex and how to fix it?

```
[user@linux]$ grep '10.1.1.[9|33]' file.txt
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.33
10.1.1.35
[user@linux]$
```

Desired Output (without .35)

```
[user@linux]$ grep '10.1.1.[regex here]' file.txt
10.1.1.9
10.1.1.33
[user@linux]$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be done with simple `grep`.

```
grep -E '10\.1\.1\.(9|33)'  Input_file
```

Where `-E` option is(from `man grep`):

> ```
>    -E, --extended-regexp
>           Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: I also suggest escaping dots as they would match any characters. `grep -E '10\.1\.1\.9|33' file.txt`

Comment: try having `1011.1.9` in file.txt

Comment: @gp42, Thanks a TON, I added them previously(after your 1st comment) but later removed them. Fixed it now, thank you.

Comment: It works! Btw, why `\\` is required in your answer? I have the same output even without `\\`

Comment: @user11392987, a single `.` means any character but when you escape them using `\.` means actual DOT(literal character) so by escaping it I am making sure it takes only literal DOT nothing else in regex.